# Как создать автоматически ярлык на рабочем столе и установить иконку в Inno Setup?

Tags: icon, windowsinstaller, inno-setup

Создаю инсталлятор своей программы. Как установить картинку для ярлыка программы? Как сделать так, чтоб после установки, ярлык автоматически появлялся на рабочем столе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Setup]
SetupIconFile=MySetupIcon.ico

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProgrammLinkName"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgramm.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyProgramm.exe"
; или так
; Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProgrammLinkName"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgramm.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyIcon.ico"
```

Попробуйте бесплатную [Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio), там есть примеры, все интуитивно понятно и можно очень многое сделать за пару щелчков мышкой.