Как сделать так, чтобы Inno Setup Compiler создавал ярлык для приложения?
Я изучаю Inno Setup Compiler, и я хочу, чтобы он автоматически создавал ярлык на рабочий стол для моего приложения.
Покопавшись в интернете я нашёл человека, который задал тот же вопрос (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526341/Как-создать-автоматически-ярлык-на-рабочем-столе-и-установить-иконку-в-inno-setu). Там ему ответили, показав два способа реализации ярлыка:
[Setup]
SetupIconFile=MySetupIcon.ico

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProgrammLinkName"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgramm.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyProgramm.exe"
; или так
; Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProgrammLinkName"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgramm.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyIcon.ico"

Мне больше понравился второй вариант. И всё бы ничего, но у меня всё равно остались вопросы, как именно этой строчкой пользоваться! Нужно ли указывать путь к программе в Filename, надо ли это делать в IconFilename, или стоит ли оставлять эти слова, как "{commondesktop}" или "{app}"?

¿А что вы уяснили по этому поводу после чтения официальной документации?

{commondesktop} - символьная ссылка на папку общего дэсктопа, в отличие от папки десктопа пользователя {userdesktop}, под которым производится установка
{app} - символьная ссылка на путь установки программы
если вы не указываете их, то где создастся ссылка и на что она будет указывать - известно только НИКОМУ.
параметр iconfile - указывает, где конкретно взять иконку с точным указанием exe или ico файла
символьные ссылки расширяются при установке в полный путь до конкретных папок на машине установки.
RTFM - https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts
